# How did Angular material UI docs achieve smooth scrolling on iOS Safari

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

iOS Safari is notorious for making pages scroll non-smooth, i.e does not appear to glide rather stop after scroll swipe ended.

But after visiting Angular and React material ui docs I noticed Angular have achieved smooth scrolling even on iOS Safari. How did they do this and how can I make a React page scroll in the same way?

Test the following two pages on iOS safari.

Example of smooth scroll https://material.angularjs.org/

Example of non smooth scroll
http://www.material-ui.com/#/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking  *How did they do that?* are off topic here.

Comment: This not not off-topic! I would like to hear the solution to this problem.